# OpenCV - How to implement FeatureDetector interface

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I am using the C++ implementation of OpenCV 2.4.6.1 for Ubuntu 12.10 on a x86_64 architecture. I am working on wrapping this [code of the Agast Corner Detector](http://www6.in.tum.de/Main/ResearchAgast) inside a class inheriting from `cv::FeatureDetector`.

Inspecting the [feature2d module header code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp) and observing other implementations, I found I should mandatory implement the `detectImpl` method:

```
virtual void detectImpl( const Mat& image, std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, const Mat& mask=Mat() ) const = 0;
```

Usually it is also implementented a method named `operator` having the following signature:

```
CV_WRAP_AS(detect) void operator()(const Mat& image, CV_OUT std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints) const;
```

Looking at other implementations I cannot say exactly what each of this methods should do. The second one `operator` I guess is somehow related to the detect method that is called for detecting keypoints:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("...");
detector->detect(img, keypoints);
```

According to your experience what's the difference between this two methods and what should each of them implement?

Related to the detector's instantiation using the factory method `cv::FeatureDetector::create` I have some clues related to the attribute `info` of type `AlgorithmInfo*` usually put as a public attribute of the detector class implementation, and using the CV_INIT_ALGORITHM in the `features2d_init` source file.

What should I implement in order to be able to instantiate my custom FeatureDetector using the factory method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a few days of work I succeeded on my commitment and learned a few lessons about implementing `cv::FeatureDetector` interface:

- Include the wrapping class into the cv namespace.
- The only method mandatory to implement is `detectImpl` using the signature of the method on the OpenCV version you are using.
- Implementing the operator method is optional, in other implementations where it is used (e.g. `MserFeatureDetector` and `StarDetector`) this method is called from `detectImpl` through the class instance:

  ```
  void ...::detectImpl( const Mat& image, std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, const Mat& mask ) const {
  ...
  (*this)(grayImage, keypoints);
  ...
  }

  void ...::operator()(const Mat& img, std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints) const{
  ...
  }
  ```
- Be aware that `detectImpl` is a const method and hence it cannot modify instance parameters so It might turn useful defining the concrete behavior of the detector on a side function as done in other detector implementations (e.g. `FastFeatureDetector` or `StarDetector`)
- To enable the wrapper to be instantiated using the factory method `cv::FeatureDetector::create` you should add to your class declaration the public method `AlgorithmInfo* info() const;` and initialize the class as an algorithm inside OpenCV using the `CV_INIT_ALGORITHM` as follows:

  ```
  namespace cv{
      CV_INIT_ALGORITHM(AgastFeatureDetector, "Feature2D.AGAST", obj.info()->addParam(obj, "threshold", obj.threshold); obj.info()->addParam(obj, "nonmaxsuppression", obj.nonmaxsuppression); obj.info()->addParam(obj, "type", obj.type));
  }
  ```

  If your class doesn't needs any parameter you can simply substitute all the params part by `obj.info()`

  Remind also to do this outside the source files where you are declaring (.h) or defining (.cpp) your wrapper and include the `opencv2/core/internal.hpp` library.

Comment: You can take a look at my implementation on my github repository [AgastFeatureDetector.h](https://github.com/gantzer89/MediaEval-PlacingTask/blob/master/include/AgastFeatureDetector.h) and [AgastFeatureDetector.cpp](https://github.com/gantzer89/MediaEval-PlacingTask/blob/master/src/AgastFeatureDetector.cpp)

Comment: Have you tried submitting this to OpenCV? It looks like it would be a valuable contribution!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Aurelius that would be nice, currently is just a wrapper of an external library and is rather far from optimal especially because of the unnecessary data structures transformation. I'll continue evolving it and I'll submit it if I achieve a reasonable performance, currently it takes around the double of the time to extract keypoints in comparison with FAST, its father, though theoretically it is faster.